# Flutter web parentheses problem with rtl language + html renderer

Tags: flutter, right-to-left, parentheses, farsi

The problem shows up when an RTL language (Persian) text containing parentheses () symbols (or <> symbols) is placed in a `Text` widget and we build for the web using html renderer (`flutter run --web-renderer html`).

This is the code (It's pictured to show the RTL as is. The text code is below):

[image: rtl text with parentheses]

Here's the result with default renderer (canvaskit on desktop) which everything sounds fine:

[image: default renderer]

The same code with html renderer:

[image: html renderer]

And if we add RTL/LTR (respectively) unicode marks before the words with parentheses, we get:

[image: added unicode marks before]

which apparently solves the problem with the word 'push'.

Here's the code as text:

```
const Text('You have pushed the button this (many) times:'),
const Text('You have pushed the (دکمه) this (many) times:'),
const Text('تعداد (دفعات) فشار دادن دکمه:', textDirection: TextDirection.rtl),
const Text('تعداد (دفعات) فشار (push) دکمه:', textDirection: TextDirection.rtl),
```

Is there a way to solve the problem in html renderer?

Comment: The problem is fixed by flutter (https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/39162). Use flutter v3.7.4 or upper for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this rendering :

```
flutter build web --no-sound-null-safety --web-renderer canvaskit
```